# Maven surefire - making dependency between tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a test class with 2 methods. These are called simultanously by the maven, so:

1. starting testA
2. starting testB
3. ending testB
4. ending testA

It weren't a problem (I like concurrent things), but currently I need to somehow guarantee these tests to be called ordently. Thus I want to start testB only after testA is ready.

I am thinking about some like a dependency between these test methods. Is it somehow possible?

Comment: First this tests are by definition no more unit tests. They are integration tests, cause there are not independent. Apart from that you have to solve this via a test framework like TestNG which can define dependencies between test methods. Furthermore they should be run by maven-failsafe-plugin cause they are integration tests. As already explained that sounds really weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JUnit has an annotation [`@FixMethodOrder`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/r4.11/src/main/java/org/junit/FixMethodOrder.java) to execute test methods in a given class in declaration order or in alphabetical order.

Surefire has a property [`runOrder`](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#runOrder) to start test classes in a given order, e.g. alphabetically.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a simple way to do this with the `surefire` plugin alone.  As the other answer indicates you can do this with a combination of techniques.

Regardless, this is a ***bad*** practice.  Unit tests should be independent.  If you have a real dependency with them, you should combine them into a single test.  Even if you can get this to work the way you want you will be working against the standard practice which will confuse others and make your setup hard to understand and maintain.